# sqlplus export vis cmd

Tags: csv, export, sqlplus

I'm trying to export some data to a CSV from sql plus via cmd line but keep getting this error:

```
SP2-0042 unknown command "  S" - rest of line ignored.
```

I'm running it like this

```
sqlplus user/pass@server @exportdata.sql
```

and the script looks like this

```
    SET UNDERLINE OFF
    SET COLSEP ,
    SET LINES 1000 PAGES 1000
    SET FEEDBACK off
    SET HEADING on
    Spool C:\NetworkThresholdTriggers\ARL1_1X.csv
    SELECT t1.BSM_NM, t1.D_DTM AS DATETIME, SUM(V_ATT_CNT) AS V_ATT_CNT, SUM(V_DRP_CALL_CNT) AS V_DRP_CALL_CNT
    FROM (SELECT BSM_NM, MAX(D_DTM) AS MAXDATETIME
    FROM DS3R_FH_1XRTT_BTS_LVL_KPI
    GROUP BY BSM_NM) t2
    INNER JOIN DS3R_FH_1XRTT_BTS_LVL_KPI t1 
    ON
    t1.BSM_NM = t2.BSM_NM                
    AND  t1.D_DTM = t2.MAXDATETIME
    AND t1.BSM_NM = 'ARL1'
    GROUP BY 
    t1.BSM_NM, t1.D_DTM
    HAVING
    CASE WHEN SUM(V_ATT_CNT) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(V_DRP_CALL_CNT)/SUM(V_ATT_CNT) END >= .01;
    Spool OFF
```

Whats weird is that if I login to sqlplus like this

```
sqlplus user/pass@server
```

and then paste in the code, it works. Why doesn't it work from a .sql file?

Answer (score 0):

figured it out, had to save as an ANSI file and not UNICODE